# Converting string to unsigned int returns the wrong result

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I have the following string:

```
sThis = "2154910440";

unsigned int iStart=atoi(sThis.c_str());
```

However the result is

```
iStart = 2147483647
```

Does anybody see my mistake?

Comment: I notice that your result is 2^31 - 1. I think it's an issue with atoi() using the highest bit as a sign bit. Maybe read the atoi() documentation closely to see what it does with signs?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`atoi` converts a string to an `int`.  On your system, an `int` is 32 bits, and its max value is 2147483647.  The value you are trying to convert falls outside this range, so the return value of `atoi` is undefined.  Your implementation, I guess, returns the max value of an `int` in this case.

You could instead use [`atoll`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi), which returns a long long, which is guaranteed to be at least 64 bits.  Or you could use a function from the [`stoi/stol/stoll`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) family, or their [unsigned counterparts](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul), which will actually give useful error reports on out of range values (and invalid values) in the form of exceptions.

Personally, I like [`boost::lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html).  Even though it appears a bit cumbersome, it can be used in a more general context.  You can use it in templates and just forward the type argument instead of having to have specializations

Comment: OP didn't said he was using C++11.

Comment: @Kyle_the_hacker: Well, it is 2013, so unless he says otherwise, I'm going to continue to assume in my answers.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Which sort of ignores reality.

Comment: @JamesKanze: To be honest, I wouldn't leave out C++11 information even if the OP explicitly stated that he couldn't use C++11.  I did provide a C++98/03 alternative anyway, so what's the problem?

Comment: I am using VS2010... Does this define which C++ I am using?

Comment: @tmighty: Your compiler has partial support for C++11, and your standard library does indeed have the family of functions I mentioned.

Answer (score 16):

You should instead use `std::strtoul`, found in `<cstdlib>`, which is designed for unsigned numbers, has a larger range, and reports errors better.

If you want to use `std::string` for input and exceptions for error handling, use `std::stoul`.  A short, highly efficient implementation would be as follows:

```
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
inline unsigned int stoui(const std::string& s)
{
    unsigned long lresult = stoul(s, 0, 10);
    unsigned int result = lresult;
    if (result != lresult) throw std::out_of_range();
    return result;
}
```

This will be much faster than `istringstream`, culture-invariant (so no unexpected changes to behavior when run in an unusual locale), completely portable, and using the third argument, you can support different numeric bases or even perform detection of `0x` and `0` prefixes.

But `unsigned int` isn't necessarily big enough to hold your value, so use `unsigned long`, and then you won't need the above wrapper.

Comment: I agree, strtoul is more portable

Comment: As far as I know unsigned long is not the same as unsigned int on some platforms and OSes. It should be different in size in Linux on x86_64 architecture.

Comment: @Sergey: Yes, which is why `strtoul` is a better choice.  One can then compare the value before and after coercion to `unsigned int` to see whether it is too large.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I do not get. Why getting potentially 64 bit value and making additional checks before downgrading to 32 bit is better than direct parsing to unsigned 32?

I see here only potential "strange" data corruption after conversion from 64bit to 32bit and compiler warnings.

Comment: @Sergey: You need unsigned long to hold this value portably.  Also I find it odd that you complain about my suggested error detection logic when you provide absolutely no error handling at all in your answer.

Comment: It is naive to think unsigned long is more portable than unsigned int. Just because sometimes it has few more bits to store more possible values?

Comment: @Sergey: the standard guarantees that the number in the question fits in unsigned long. There is no such guarantee for unsigned int.

Comment: given that `std::strtoul` only exists since c++11, I wonder why no `std::strtou` for `unsigned int` was added too.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818: You are mistaken.  `strtoul` has been around since C89.  Perhaps you meant `std::stoul`, the function that takes a `std::string` input?  The `sto*` functions correspond to the `strto*` functions, which is why there is no `stoui`.

Comment: I think it was a typo and I meant `std::strtoull` which is indicated as "since C++11" [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtoul). I admit that I don't remember what or why I was actually missing :(

Answer (score 11):

atoi returns a signed int, which on your platform has a max value of `2^31-1`.

It doesn't matter what you're assigning that result to, it will be bounded by the return type.

C++ streams can read unsigned ints.

```
std::istringstream reader(sThis);
unsigned int val;
reader >> val;
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget, you can always write your own function that does **exactly** what you want.

This code will work with any number between -9223372036854775806 (2^63+1) and 9223372036854775807 (2^63-1) *inclusive.*

Something like this:

```
long long int myAtoi ( string str ) {
    long long int value = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++) {

        if (str[i] != '-') {
            value *=  10;
            value += (int) ((str[i]) - '0');
        }
    }


    if (str.size() > 0 && str[0] == '-')
        return -value;
    else
        return value;
}
```

Comment: As given this function handles minus signs too liberally and would treat a string like "-----10----33---5-8-9-" by returning -1033589.

Answer (score 1):

An unsigned int is often a 32 bit value in C++ which has a maximum of 4,294,967,295.
2,154,710,440 can therefore be represented as an unsigned int. However, atoi converts to an int which is signed and has a maximum value of  2,147,483,647 - so you string overflows the value range whichis why your answer is incorrect. You could use atoll which converts your string to a long long which will be at least 64 bits. 
Integer sizes are compiler dependent in C++. It is often better to include the header file stdint.h and then use uint32_t or uint64_t and so on, so that you know the size you are dealing with.

Answer (score 1):

you can use atol which convert string to long int .
To read more see the man atol in Linux.

the prototype

```
#include <stdlib.h>
long atol(const char *nptr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately C++ has no embedded implementation for parsing unsigned int and this is really strange.

Here is a code which can help you:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sstream>

inline unsigned int stoui(const std::string& s)
{
    std::istringstream reader(s);
    unsigned int val = 0;
    reader >> val;
    return val;
}

// This may be not the same as stoui on some platforms:
inline uint32_t stoui32(const std::string& s)
{
    std::istringstream reader(s);
    uint32_t val = 0;
    reader >> val;
    return val;
}
```

Comment: It's because no one ever needed one.  `strtoul` works perfectly well for parsing any valid `unsigned int` value, and detecting overflow requires just a single extra comparison.  In short, doing so is orders of magnitude more efficient than the broken (utterly lacking in error detection) code which you provided.

Comment: BTW, downvoting for regurgitating [an existing answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18037886/103167).

Comment: @BenVoigt: You are suggesting bad solution. Unfortunately I can't put code sample right here, so I updated my reply to main question.

Comment: No that is not what I suggested.

Comment: I edited my answer to show what I meant by "One can then compare the value before and after coercion to unsigned int to see whether it is too large"

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Now I agree. Your solution is more correct because it is closer to what C++ standard requires from stoul when input data is out of range. Right?

Comment: Well, I probably wouldn't use exceptions for handling out-of-range data myself, but it makes it very clear to a reader "you must put your error-handling logic here".  I see the main advantages being the ones I listed in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This code will convert it with C++11:

```
std::string sThis = "2154910440";
unsigned int iStart = static_cast<unsigned int>(std::stoul(sThis));
```

`std::stoul` will return an `unsigned long`, which is larger than an `unsigned int`.

`static_cast` will convert it to the right type.

Comment: An `unsigned long` *may* be larger than `unsigned int` - but it's also allowed to be the same size.

Comment: Will the `static_cast` throw an error, similar to @BenVoigt solution?