# How to convert a string say "test" to unsigned int in c++

Tags: c++, string, mfc, type-conversion

I have to use an encryption algorithm which takes unsigned int as an input. For this I want to convert my password which is alpha numeric 8 character string to int.

I am using the below code and not sure if it works right. I want to convert my characters say "test" to unsigned integer.

I do get an output value. But I'm not sure if this is the right way of doing this and if there can be any side effects.

Can you please explain what actually is happening here?

```
unsigned int ConvertStringToUInt(CString Input)
{
    unsigned int output;
    output = ((unsigned int)Input[3] << 24);
    output += ((unsigned int)Input[2] << 16);
    output += ((unsigned int)Input[1] << 8);
    output += ((unsigned int)Input[0]);
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Even with Base64, it won't fit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting string to unsigned int returns the wrong result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18037835/converting-string-to-unsigned-int-returns-the-wrong-result)

Comment: It depends on what you want "testing" to mean. Yeah this is a way to look at it but we don't know if thats what you want

Comment: In your case your unsigned int can hold 4 bytes, and the string "testing" consists of 7 bytes (not counting the nul terminator). You need to tell us how you want these 7 bytes mapped to 4 bytes, and which bytes you e.g. want to lose or throw away, and which order you want the bytes from your string to map to the bytes in the unsigned int

Comment: I have to use an encryption algorithm which take unsigned int as an input. For this i want to convert my password which is alpha numeric 8 character string to int . Any possible solutions ?

Comment: I got the above code from internet. Not sure if that works too. Can anyone explain me what this is actually doing. By the way i am splitting my string to 4 character each and then sending it to this function. So that should work i think.

Comment: How does the above code fail to work for you? Have you tested that it does what you need?

Comment: I do get an output value. But not sure if this right way of doing and if there can be any side effects. Can you please explain what actually is happening here.

Comment: Can you please explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: Actually this reads like a typical  [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 2):

For an input of `"ABCD"` the output of `ConvertStringToUInt` will be `0x44434241` because:

- 0x41 is the ASCII code of `'A'`
- 0x42 is the ASCII code of `'B'`
- 0x43 is the ASCII code of `'C'`
- 0x44 is the ASCII code of `'D'`

`<<` being the *shift left* operator.

So we have:

```
0x44 << 24 = 0x44000000
0x43 << 16 = 0x00430000
0x42 << 8  = 0x00004200

output =
          0x44000000
        + 0x00430000
        + 0x00004200
        + 0x00000041
        ============
          0x44434241
```

Be aware that your `ConvertStringToUInt` function only works if the length of the provided string is **exactly 4**, so this function is useless for your case because the length of your password is **8**.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do a unique mapping of a 8 character alphanumeric string to a 32 bit integer.

- (10 + 26 + 26) ^ 8 is 218,340,105,584,896  (digits + upper-case and lower-case letters)
- (10 + 26) ^ 8 is 2,821,109,907,456 (digits + case-insensitive letters)
- 2 ^ 32 is 4,294,967,296 (a 32 bit unsigned int)

So if you need to convert your 8 characters into a 32 bit number, you will need to use hashing.   And that means that *multiple* passwords will map to the same key.

Note that this NOT encryption because the mapping is not reversible.  It **cannot** be reversible.  This can be proven mathematically.

The Wikipedia page on [hash functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) is a good place to start learning about this.  Also the page on the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).

---

However, it should also be noted that 8 character passwords are too small to be secure.  And if you are hashing to a 32 bit code, brute-force attacks will be easy.

Comment: I am novice in this. Can you please explain. By the way i would need only 4 character (32 bit) to 32 bit integer.

Comment: It you only need a 4 character to 32 bit mapping, your code does that already.  (Modulo possible bugs ....)

Comment: @InfinityCoder in your question you write that your password is 8 characters. Your `ConvertStringToUInt` function is perfectly fine for exactly 4 characters.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is to reinvent a hashing algorithm, very poorly. I strongly recommend to use SHA-256 or some equivalent hashing algorithm available by the libs of your system, which is best practice and usually sufficient to transmit and compare passwords.

You should start reading the basics on that issue before writing any more code, else the security level of your application won't be much better than no hashing/encryption at all, but with the false sense of being on the safe side. [Start here](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm), for instance.

Comment: Sorry, but secure hashing algorithms are hardly applicable to this particular problem.  The size of the domain and range are so small that brute-force guessing would defeat any secure hashing scheme.  (8 character passwords, 32-bit hashes ......)